# Install a running Magento site in Localhost

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to Install a live Magento site in Localhost. I am using Windows 8 and XAMPP. While I am trying to install the site I am getting below error.

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "" in D:\php\htdocs\magento\lib\Aitoc\Aitpagecache\Mainpage.php on line 597

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "" in D:\php\htdocs\magento\lib\Aitoc\Aitpagecache\Mainpage.php on line 597

Fatal error: Call to a member function getCode() on boolean in D:\php\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Model\Session.php on line 71
```

Could anyone say what is the solution??

Comment: Remove your cache tag from local.xml because we do not require cache in localhost.

Comment: If above solution will not work then disable Aitoc Cache module from etc/modules.